# syntax match: redundant end of line marker "$"

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I am looking to create a new syntax. This is what I have so far:

```
syntax match jl_comment "^# .*"
```

but I have noticed other examples using pattern like this:

```
"^# .*$"
```

Example:

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/12f20038/runtime/syntax/sh.vim#L385

This is confusing to me. With my example, the `.` matches anything, so it
will continue until the end of line. So it seems the `$` is redundant. Is that
the case, or am I misunderstanding the rules?

Comment: That's the case. Yes it's redundant. But it's more explicit and it doesn't hurt. I'd be fine with either expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to define a Region instead of Match:

```
syn region jl_comment start=/^# / end=/$/
hi link jl_comment Comment
```

This also has the benefit of allowing different highlighting for the marker,
should you want to do that:

```
syn region comment_text matchgroup=comment_mark start=/^# / end=/$/
hi link comment_mark Delimiter
hi link comment_text Comment
```